# Mesh moving with Bone after having deselcted all in Weight Paint

Tags: rigging

I've just started my first real Blender project and i had to add some Bones to my Figure. Eventually after deselecting all vertices with Weight Paint, that Mesh is still moving with the Bone.
 [image: Shoulderbone and hips and body moving with it]

I really hope anyone of you can help me and I've already tried a lot, like selecting all vertices and making their weight to 0.

Greetings

W.Zayde

Comment: Try uploading .blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: as mentioned by @Georges, provide your .blend file to be able to help you